# How to implement Sovos TaxCalculation Extension in Magento 2.2.6

Tags: magento2, extensions, magento2.2.6, tax-calculation

I am **implementing Sovos TaxCalculation extension in Magento2.2.6**, according to the documentation I have to use this URL **core_adapter/api/magento**, which is not actually working for me, because I really don't know what should I do with this ( core_adapter/api/magento ) path, I don't have any path like that in my whole system. Let suppose if I create that path, then what are the files or code I need to put here.

Comment: Did you implement Sovos Tax Module. Please let me know steps as well. I am facing issue as well.

Comment: I am working on other modules like card and orders, after that, I'll start work again on it.